# Node dependency package.json metadata changing over time (for same version)

Tags: node.js, npm

NPM: version 2.2.0. 
Operating System: Windows 8.1.

Over time, I see that many of my node dependencies have their package.json metadata changed, even though the version number of the dependency does not change. This happens most frequently with the homepage attribute within package.json.

As an example, this is currently happening with the "is-utf8@0.2.0" package. My npm cache was populated locally and on our CI server about 1 month ago. At that time, the package.json file of this module contained a homepage attribute. Today, if I do a "npm remove is-utf8 && npm clear cache is-utf8" then npm will download version 0.2.0 again and install it. However, this time the package.json is missing the homepage attribute.

This happens fairly consistently with 4-5 modules every two weeks. I know this because my nightly builds are always using an npm cache and they never complain about missing homepages. But my release builds (once a week) often complain about 4-5 modules missing homepages.

Why does this happen? 
Is it possible that the .tgz file is being updated for so many projects?

UPDATE: In the last week, 12 of my dependencies had their homepage disappear from the package.json.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `homepage` field is set from the github url when `normalize-package-data` is run.  This is not consistently happening when you do the install with a clear vs. primed cache.

It looks like you have found a bug in `npm` -- thanks!  I have created an issue on `npm`'s github issue tracker https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/7243